# Hold div untill animations are done

Tags: html, css, animation, skrollr

I'm working with the Skrollr plugin and I'm trying to create a part where the right div will be stuck' while the left div has to scroll past all kinds of images/animations. How can I hold that div there?

this is the plugin: 
https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

This is what I have now, it's all just very simple and in the early stage.

HTML:

```
<div class="screenheight slide">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left-col">
      <div data-200="opacity:0; width:10em;" data-800="opacity:1;" class="large-img"><img src="img/schoen.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 92%;
  max-width: 78em;
  top: 25%;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

.left-col {
  margin-left: 0%;
  text-align: right;
  width: 49.5%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.left-col img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -5em auto 0;
}

.right-col {
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 49.5%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.right-col img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -5em auto 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete code. Im sure you are missing some code block.

Comment: Just the body tags, script links and other little CSS styling. I can start from scratch if I have to, so please don't assume any other code or tags. I just really don't know HOW to approach it. (I added my current code because that's usually what users on SO want).

Comment: i checked the link you have mentioned and it shows some js code too...